# how to use a java spinner

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jspinner

I am trying to create a j option pane that allows the user to pick a number between 0-200 using a spinner and then set an integer variable from this spinner I have done this

```
SpinnerNumberModel sModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 200, 1);
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(sModel);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, spinner);
```

however I cant work out how to assign a variable to it or insure the input is only a number.

also less of an issue but I also would like a message that says "pick a number between 1-200"

Comment: *"however I cant work out how to assign a variable to it or insure the input is only a number."* Seriously? Change `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, spinner);` to `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, spinner); int i = sModel.getNumber().intValue();`!  *"also less of an issue but I also would like a message that says "pick a number between 1-200""* Read the Java Docs and look through the overloaded variants of `showMessageDialog`..

Comment: or ``(Integer) spinner.getValue();`

Comment: Thanks for the help that works now however if I enter "A" it defaults to the lowest number rather than forcing them to select a number